# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when sending message from WildFly 10 to remote ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: wildfly, activemq-artemis

We're working on a JMS based application deployed under WildFly 10. Now we're migrating from the embedded ActiveMQ Artemis server to a standalone one.

The same application server hosts a JBPM instance (version 6.5). When we try to send messages we have this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.getContextClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader.
```

We think there is a compatibility problem on Netty, so we also tried to install another Netty version on JBoss but it doesn't work and the server doesn't start.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Move to a newer WildFly version, it has also a nicer support for remote Artemis

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ Artemis are you using now for the standalone broker? Are you trying to send messages from JBoss? If not, where are you sending the message from? Where are you seeing this error exactly? Is it on the sender or on the broker?

Comment: We're using 2.24 version of ActiveMQ Artemis , we're trying to send messages from a jar embedded into JBPM.war since WildFly runs with java version 1.8.0_152. We're using artemis-jms-client-all-2.19.0.jar. The error shows up when we try to send messages into WildFly logs.